# How to catch a string based on a subsection of it

Tags: python, regex

I have multiple strings in a list.

Each list is a link in a string format.

I have some strings whose style is the following:

`mailto:newsletter.dcda@dcda.com`

Some of these strings change in the @ part. They have different addresses.

I want to find a regular expression that can capture the whole text based on the `mailto:`

part.

Comment: So you want to extract just the email address, or including the `mailto:` part as well? Did you search for "*regex capture email address*", and if so why didn't the existing results work for you?

Comment: I want to extract the whole string, including the address.

Comment: If you want to catch the whole line, you can check if `mailto` is in that line, no regex needed? `if 'mailto' in line.lower(): ` something like that? If that is not what you want provide a line and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this expression will work

```
import re

t='mailto:newsletter.dcda@dcda.com'
re.findall('mailto:(?:\w+\.?)+@(?:\w+\.?)+',t)

['mailto:newsletter.dcda@dcda.com']
```

[RegExp test](https://regex101.com/r/yysFsH/1)